# Shellscript backslashed and spaced parameter

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

So, what I'm trying to do is if the user didn't pass a path as argument to script, the script shall use the current directory. If a path is passed use it instead.

```
instdir="$(pwd)/"
if [ -n "$1" ] ; then
  instdir="$1"
fi
cd $instdir
```

Errors

`./script.sh /path/to/a\ folder/`

*outputs*: `cd: /path/to/a: File or folder not found`

`./script.sh "/path/to/a\ folder/"`

*outputs*: `cd: /path/to/a\: File or folder not found`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing `cd $instdir` to  `cd "$instdir"` should fix that particular problem.  Without the quotes, the `a` and `folder` parts of `a folder` are treated as separate parameters.

Note, instead of the three-line `if` statement to set `instdir`, write:

```
[ "$1" ] && instdir="$1"
```

Comment: I would not advice that last one, without the explicit comment that  the "longer" if statement is simply more readable and maintainable. If it's a small script, it's OK. But a larger, professionally written, mass-distributed installation script -- no way.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass a path with spaces in it as an argument, it will cause problems. If not now, then in the future. I'd suggest you do the following (provided the path is the only argument):

```
instdir="$(pwd)"

if [[ -d "$@" ]]; then
  instdir="$@"  
fi

cd "$instdir"
```